# Problemas con el dismiss();

Tags: android

tengo incovenientes con el "dismiss();" al parecer no me reconoce su evento, por favor que me pueda orientar, que estoy haciendo mal

Este es el XML (2 botones) solo tengo los 2 botones con el android:onClick="onClick"

este el código del Onclick

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_peso_button:
                dialogo = new Dialog(v.getContext());
                dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.activity_modal_info_prod);
                dialogo.setCancelable(true);
                dialogo.show();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_add_car:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_close_infopro:
                dialogo.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el error que me sale :(
[image: error del que me lanza el codigo]

Comment: No es suficiente el código que muestras para determinar dónde está el error. Lo que te puedo decir, con el código que muestras, es que al entrar al evento `onClick()` con el view `R.id.btn_close_infopro` la variable `dialog` es `null`. Sugiero que verifiques desde dónde está declarada esa variable, dónde se supone que debe asignársele un valor y dónde es probable que lo esté perdiendo. Como te he dicho, lo que se puede definir al 100% es que al entrar a este evento, la variable vale `null`, por lo que no hace referencia a ningún dialogo (aunque se esté mostrando uno).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe poder reconocer el método `.dismiss()` sin problema, pero debes revisar si el diálogo aún esta mostrándose y existe, si no es así vas a obtener el error que expones.

Valida el caso en el cual el diálogo fue cerrado y ya no existe.

```
...
...
 if(dialogo != null) {
   dialogo.dismiss();
   break;
 }
...
...
```

Comment: Estimado gracias por responder, ya hice ese proceso, esta vez no me dio error, pero no me cierra el dialog :/

Comment: Precisamente eso es lo que realiza el dismiss() , que deseas realizar en lugar de cerrarlo?